# Skype chatbot not updating to latest publish

Tags: skype, botframework

I'm having trouble with microsoft chatbot on skype. The chatbot on skype not updating to latest bot I published from the visual studio. Here some screenshot of that.

Emulator Version (The right one, the test chatbot from the developer portal is the same response as this)
[image]

The skype version (The response is from my old version of chatbot script)

[image]

This is the ngrok inspection (all 200, In other word it's getting to the server, though it's wrong)

[image]

The AppID is e1425cb5-f16e-4c64-80d7-82b29d742268 and I've tried it from azure, too. The response is the same and for additional information the channels are not yet published + skype is up to date. Anyone get this strange bug too?

**EDIT 1: Additional Information**

After I use some breakpoint. The skype and emulator both catch the breakpoint on this one.

[image]

The strange things is, the skype one catch on this scripts (SimpleDialogFxm) which is my old one.

[image]

While the emulator one is catch on the right scripts (SimpleDialogue).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try sending a /deleteprofile message to the Skype bot. It might be possible the the Skype bot is relying on the dialog state.

By sending that message you will force the bot to delete all the information in the data bags.

Comment: Do I need to do it in skype bot chat window? It return : Available commands:
 /me [text]
 /add [skypename+]
 /alertson [text]
 /alertsoff
 /wikimarkup
 /help
For more help please see http://www.skype.com/go/help.chathelp

Comment: I already tried the /deleteprofile command in developer portal. The skype still not updated after re-adding. While typing /deleteprofile in skype still give me the help of skype (available command.....)

Comment: After some searching. I need to use a space before /deleteprofile in the skype chat. Now it worked. Thank you

Comment: had same issue and the solution works for me as well - however this seems like a bug in skype? i cannot ask all users to delete their profile every time i release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. The solution was to remove the bot from Skype contacts list and add again.
Also note, that the bot is not updated on Skype when we change it's name, profile picture or description. Seems it's a bug.

Comment: I already tried to remove and add it again from developer web. It's still not working. What you mean 'remove from contact' is right clicking on the bot name in skype and click the remove from contact button, right? I haven't change the name, profile picture or the description, too

Comment: Yup, already try that. then re-add the bot from the developer portal

Comment: I've forgot to mention that also I closed ngrok before restarting Bot.
Have you tried it?
If not then try to close it, restart the project (on VS) and run ngrok again.
(Note: You'll have to update endpoint link with new ngrok link in dev portal)

Comment: I've tried it, just now. It's still not working. I've restarted ngrok, VS, skype and even reloading the developer portal page after changing the endpoint