# Web chat and telegram channel not working

Tags: botframework, telegram

I have built a bot in massively.ai and set it all up in the Microsoft Bot framework. I have submitted it for review and it has been reviewed and published. 
It is working fine in Skype, but does not work on the "web chat" channel or the Telegram channel. It also doesn't work in the test area on the MS Bot landing page

[image: [Screenshot of MS bot landing page]]

Comment: It could be this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198776/skype-chatbot-not-updating-to-latest-publish/42198999#42198999

Comment: You have any error? Can you debug it locally to see what happens or discard any deploy issue?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Skype is fine, its the other channels that are not. With regards debugging locally, how do I do this? All i have at the moment is the Massively.ai web interface and the https://dev.botframework.com/bots web interface. how can I debug locally?

Comment: Just to update this, I have found that it only works on my skype account, and not anyone elses.. so effectively all the channels are behaving as if they are unpublished, even though they are all published! 
I also noticed if I click on the "Published" drop down in the top right and click on "View in Bot Directory" I get an error message "An error has occurred."
I feel there is an error on the Microsoft side for me. Does anyone know how I can contact them?

Comment: I am with Microsoft, we are looking into it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can debug locally by clicking the "configure continuous integration button" in Azure. You will get a .zip file with the source code and then you can open it in VS or your editor of choice.

[image: DebugLocally]

But since you are using Massively.ai what you could do is use or create a Trace class and use it in the Catch section of a Try/Catch to track and store errors and then show them in the Bot Framework emulator log. That might give you more information about the problem.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Trace.TraceError("Some error in class X" + e.ToString());
    return null;
}
```

To test the same bot in the emulator, you will need to find the end point, application ID and password for the bot service. The Settings tab only provides the partial message endpoint (ending with three dots). Therefore you will need to go to the developer site, https://dev.botframework.com/. Click on the Edit link. You will find the message endpoint there. Copy the entire URL and enter it in the emulator. Also, copy and paste the application ID and password from the bot developer portal.

You will also need to download the free tool, ngrok, which creates a tunnel between the bot hosted remotely (in this case on Massively.ai) and your computer behind the firewall. Click App Settings in the emulator. Browse to the location where ngrok.exe is located. Save the setting. The utility will be launched automatically from the emulator. At this point, the emulator is ready. Click “Connect” or the refresh icon. When you type something in the input box, You will see a response:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have done as you suggest, installed and set up the emulator with the correct endpoint, secret, and ngrok. I am getting the same issue, not replies coming in to the emulator from the bot (same on the web and telegram channel, but for some reason it works on Skype)

Skype - [link](https://join.skype.com/bot/932205eb-007f-4b98-9c82-4665c13fb818 )

Web - [link](https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/age_of_consent_bot?s=lSZzH0qX2Gc.cwA.PaY.4aXLVB4aMZSJavFVTWQB-s5npGaNX_hxa8XfQ0yey48)
Telegram - [link](https://telegram.me/Age_of_consent_bot )

Comment: Screenshot of emulator https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM6ygoFyrz0-PllzWfaRSqZwmDyvnVxA4IExbdpWyG-XljYS0Z7_Hksu7KyXaZrZg?key=OFItdE9fTGJWbUtDLWpqS2tuUFA0c2JJSFI1NTJR

Comment: You are welcome! I see that the emulator is trying to find the controller that manages incoming messages at /botframework /receive. Please make sure that is indeed where the controller resides. Normally you define the route to the controller in the configuration like this:             
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }); Also if possible you could try to download the code from Massively.ai in a local solution and debug it more easily. I will keep looking into this.

Comment: For anyone following this, I have just heard back from Massively and they do not support any channels other than Skype through the MS bot network at present. This is why it isn't working for me and others