# Skype bot not responding

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype

I had developed a bot on the Microsoft Bot framework. It is running fine on the web chat channel. However when I add it to the Skype channel, bot is not responding to my messages. I am not getting any error either(the bot has been added to few skype contacts).
Also there was an existing bot which was added to web-chat and skype channels. this second bot was working fine in both the channels till last week. Since last Friday none of the skype bots are responding.
Is there any ongoing issue at the Microsoft side?

I am using NodeJs for coding.

Code is not attached as the bot is working as needed on the Web Chat channel.

Update:

The bot miraculously started working today. thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Bot Builder SDK?

Comment: Yes, I am using the botbuilder 3.9.1 version.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198776/skype-chatbot-not-updating-to-latest-publish/42198999#42198999

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: Right now there is no known issue with Skype.  What is your bot handle and or app id so we can take a look?

Comment: @JasonSowers Currently the bot is responding regularly but throwing this error at certain points. No clue what this error is about:

Error: Request to 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/29%3A1r7M8Z1GxDAsWPxGYOZl6kuBBtX8csrrh5ujE7mGFvyI/activities' failed: [400] Bad Request